# compare choice value in template

Tags: django

I couldnt find answer for this..

I have a model
class Test which has a field `status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default='1')`
then I have class Status:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    STATUSES = (
        ('1', 'ONE'),
        ('2', 'TWO'),
        ('3', 'THREE'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUSES, unique=True)
```

now, in template, I want to compare whether the Status choice is 'ONE' :

```
{% for test in foo.test_set.all %}
    {% if test.get_status_display == 'ONE' %}
```

This condition is not working but if I print the value of status in the loop it prints 'ONE':

```
{{ test.get_status_display }} #prints 'ONE'
```

Comment: Really? With the code you have here, you would need to print `test.get_name_display`.

Comment: The only way you would get that result is `status.get_name_display` - which I don't see anywhere? From test, you would need `test.status.get_name_display`; or more practically, use the database value not the display equivalent in order to make your code more flexible: `{% if test.status.name == "1" %}`

Comment: Thanks guys, my overseight, i forgot to call name property like you adviced.